# (Bootstrap 3) How to have navbar on small screens appear the same as navbar on big screens

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, navigation

I'm creating a bootstrap navbar that is fixed to the top of the screen, but on small screens I don't want the hamburger button that drops down the text to appear. Instead I just want the text to appear on the navbar like it does on large screens.

This is my navbar code

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="active"><a href="home.html">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

How, on small screens, do I make the text on the navbar appear the same as the text on the navbar on big screens?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think the `navbar-collapse` class is responsible for the hamburger behavior.

Comment: I tried taking it out but it didn't work. Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ## [Changing the collapsed mobile navbar breakpoint](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar)
>
> The navbar collapses into its vertical mobile view when the viewport is narrower than `@grid-float-breakpoint`, and expands into its horizontal non-mobile view when the viewport is at least `@grid-float-breakpoint` in width. Adjust this variable in the [Less](http://lesscss.org) source to control when the navbar collapses/expands. The default value is `768px` (the smallest "small" or "tablet" screen).

Here's where that specific variable lives: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/57260f16b364e4cb559cd65159197fd1cf5248f7/less/variables.less#L321

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="navbar-header">
    <button data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-9" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" type="button">       
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Brand</a>
</div>
<div id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-9" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        ...
    </ul>
</div>
```

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-inverted